# How to create new user with read only permission

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a folder on a linux server that is set to full access to a group. I want to add a user that can access the folder with read only permissions. The group should remain as full access.

Thanks!

Comment: Use ACL settings. setfacl and getfacl. The syntax would be  sudo setfacl -m -R -d u:USERNAME:rx DIRECTORY  and without the R and d flags to the files in the dir ( and drop the x). I might be off syntactically so this a comment not an answer.